# What is the recommended CPU usage on Cassandra nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I am running datastax 4.5 version of cassandra. What is the recommended CPU usage on cassandra nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the CPU usage on cassandra nodes should not go beyond 50%. But you may notice high CPU usage during repairs and compactions.